# How to fix Form over the slider image

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and creating a website.
I am trying to fix user check availability form over my slider images but I didn't get output what I want.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="index.html" class="default-form">
    <span class="arrival calendar">
        <input type="text" name="arrival" placeholder="Arrival" data-dateformat="m/d/y">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="departure calendar">
        <input type="text" name="departure" placeholder="Departure" data-dateformat="m/d/y">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="adults select-box">
        <select name="adults" data-placeholder="Adults">
            <option>Adults</option>
            <option value="1">1 adult</option>
            <option value="2">2 adults</option>
            <option value="3">3 adults</option>
            <option value="4">4 adults</option>
         </select>
     </span>
     <span class="children select-box">
         <select name="children" data-placeholder="Children">
            <option>Children</option>
            <option value="1">1 children</option>
            <option value="2">2 childrens</option>
            <option value="3">3 childrens</option>
            <option value="4">4 childrens</option>
          </select>
       </span>
       <span class="submit-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-transparent">Book Now</button>
           <a href="#" class="advanced">Advanced Search</a>
       </span>
</form>
```

Here is Css code:

```
#banner #hero-tabs .tab-content-list {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#banner #hero-tabs .tab-content-list .tab-content {
  display: none;
}
```

Please Help me out to find how to fix form over image slider.

Comment: Can you supply a link to working code?

Comment: I am working on localhost so how i provide link..suggest

Comment: In the above code, where are the slider images you referenced?

Comment: <div class="banner-bg">
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><img src="img/banner-bg-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><img src="img/banner-bg-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><img src="img/banner-bg-3.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><img src="img/banner-bg-4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>

Comment: what specified in z-index ..RRR

Comment: sorry no need to specify z-index just make position absolute... check https://jsfiddle.net/fnhxo61m/